# Unbalanced left and right channel in lower volume levels - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have this problem when I adjust my volume and some volume levels below 55 become unbalanced, the unbalanced channel never seems to be more than 2 levels of difference but it can be quite the annoyance once you notice one channel isn't outputting the same volume when wearing good headphones.

There is a Microsoft KB article describing the problem, the article has a 'resolution' but its more of a description of the bug than anything - 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2005797

> Resolution:
>   The issue should not appear once the volume reaches higher volume levels. Left and Right channel volume can also be adjusted manually via Sound Property in Control Panel

Really curious if there is a fix or whether I should just put up with it, also I'm using an AsRock motherboard that uses a Realtek ALC892 for audio if that is of any relevance to the bug.

Video of me adjusting volume which shows the volume unbalancing below 55 volume https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7P9nKYD219ydVJMYUdfRW5KZVU

Comment: Is Windows 32-bit or 64-bit? Which driver version are you currently using?

Comment: 64 bit SP1, Realtek driver version is 6.0.1.6873 which is the latest.

Comment: Actually that driver version is not the latest one. What's the [hardware ID](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Hardware-ID) of the audio card?

Comment: HDAUDIO\FUNC_01&VEN_10EC&DEV_0892&SUBSYS_18498892&REV_1003             
What is the latest version and can you link to it, because I checked on the realtek site and it was the latest.

Comment: Ok, I see there was a newer version of the Audio driver(.7083) but as expected that didn't fix it since it was just compatibility fixes.

Comment: Here's a more up-to-date version (`6.0.1.7195`) straight from the Microsoft Update Catalog: http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/driver/drvs/2014/03/20635257_bf96457336883f69f8156a5bf545ca9c2b476444.cab You'll need to extract the `.cab` archive (e.g. using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)) and then [install it manually](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-install-hardware-or-device-drivers-manually-in-windows-vista/).

Comment: Ok I updated to .7195 and as expected it didn't fix it, I'm not even sure that version is meant for Windows 7. Thanks for the help, anyway.

Comment: As you can read on the [main download page](http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/ScopedViewRedirect.aspx?updateid=008bfc3a-52bb-4cb3-b068-d6e7143c50a2), the driver does support Windows 7. You wouldn't have been to install it otherwise. Anyway, if you still get the same issues with a newer driver, it's probably safe to say it's not a driver-related issue. What happens if you boot any Linux live distribution?